# How to tunnel all traffic of a QEMU VM through a Proxy?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, proxy, qemu

I'm trying to make a VM in which all its traffic goes through a proxy (like a tor proxy or any other ip/port proxy). I've found [this article](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2017-05/msg01433.html) showing that it is possible in command line, however I'm using the GUI manager ([virtual manager](https://virt-manager.org/)) and didn't found in anywhere a place to setup a proxy for the VM. So I'm asking if is it possible to make through the GUI?

I want to make it on the host machine so it doesn't happen to make any connection by mistake inside the virtual machine to outside using my default connection.